# Can I embed common applications like command prompt into a java fx application with JNA?And if so, how do I get started with JNA?

Tags: java, javafx, jna

I'm currently working on a JavaFX application and long story short, I'm figuring some functionalities as I go. However, I've now reached a point where I want my application to start a shell with the press of a button, and according to the operating system the corresponding terminal should start. I did some digging and searching and found out that Runtime.getRuntime.exec() is useful when a developer wants to run a specific amount of commands and get their result but doesn't keep the terminal open. Then I searched a bit more and found another StackOverflow post mentioning that I can display an external application inside my JavaFX window through JNA and the winAPI. Is this something that indeed JNA and winAPI can do, and if so how do I get started with JNA since there is a limited amount of resources online?

Comment: You can look at projects such as [JediTerm](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm) to see what they do.

Comment: Ok, thanks. They actually have full documentation, nice!